# Connector/C mysql for C language

Tags: mysql, c

i wasted my whole night searching for this solution to connect mysql with C.
I just started working with C few days ago and wanted to use MYSQL.

if found this small script but it doesn't work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
printf("MySQL client version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());

exit(0);
}
```

Here is the error that i get

```
\Local\Temp\ccV0Dljg.o:mysql.c:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `mysql_get_client_info@0'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 1.1s]
```

i am using windows 10, i found some sites telling about linux and ubunto installation but i need a solution for windows.

i am using Connector/C 6.1.6 Windows (x86, 32-bit), MSI Installer

Comment: describe your development and server environment better

Comment: i have a xampp server which i use for php , c compiler name gnu gcc.

Comment: And is mysql.h in your compilers path?

Comment: describe what sort of windows solution you are looking for. like sentences. many. And do it in the question area via an [edit], not down here in comments. You said you need a solution for Windows.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i meant to say if there is an easy way to connect mysql to c?

Comment: and how can i add mysql.h in my compiler path? sorry i am not much familiar with compiler. all i know how to compile a file.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain to us how you compile the file then - the error implies you are not linking with the MySQL library so knowing how you compiled it is important.

Comment: According to the first MySQL C code tutorial I found on the internet you need to run `mysql_config --cflags --libs` and add whatever it prints to the end of your compile command - I can't try it because I don't know what compiler you are using or how you invoke it.

Comment: Also you may want to read the documentation.  It has lots of good stuff: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-building-clients.html   Actually, having read it a bit more, it tells you exactly what to do...